# Pivot column into NxM table in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, pandas, clickhouse

Imagine I have a table like

```
col_a  col_b col_c
one    a     1.0
one    b     2.0
two    a     3.0
two    b     4.0
```

And I wanted to transform it into

```
     a   b
one  1.0  2.0
two  3.0  4.0
```

I know it can be done in Postgres with [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html) or in Pandas with [df.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) or [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Can it be done in ClickHouse?

Comment: You should not tag question with databases you are not using.

Comment: I removed the `postgresql` tag as you seem to be using Clickhouse which is a totally different DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

```
create table t123(col_a String, col_b String, col_c Float64) Engine=Memory;

insert into t123 values('one','a',1.0),('one','b',2.0),('two','a',3.0),('two','b',4.0);

select col_a, (sumMap( g.1, g.2 )) from (
select col_a, groupArray( (col_b, col_c) ) as g from t123 group by col_a)
group by col_a;

┌─col_a─┬─sumMap(tupleElement(g, 1), tupleElement(g, 2))─┐
│ two   │ (['a','b'],[3,4])                              │
│ one   │ (['a','b'],[1,2])                              │
└───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘



select col_a, arrayZip( (sumMap( g.1, g.2 ) as x).1, x.2) r from (
select col_a, groupArray( (col_b, col_c) ) as g from t123 group by col_a)
group by col_a;

┌─col_a─┬─r─────────────────┐
│ two   │ [('a',3),('b',4)] │
│ one   │ [('a',1),('b',2)] │
└───────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an incomplete solution. After all, the Topikstarter gave an ordinary table for input, and at the output he asked for a table with n columns, without arrays, but you gave him a solution with tuple at the output.
How can this be further turned into a normal table? Could you tell me, please?

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres (using the SQL standard) you can achieve a pivot this way:

```
SELECT
    col_a,
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN col_b = 'a' THEN col_c 
           ELSE 0 
       END
    ) as a,
    SUM(
       CASE WHEN col_b = 'b' THEN col_c 
           ELSE 0 
       END
    ) as b
FROM mytable
GROUP BY col_a
```

I am not into ClickHouse but I guess, there are opportunities to create conditional expressions (something like `CASE` or `IF`) which can be combined with an aggregate function (like `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`, ... everything works in that specific case.)